# How to add buttons dynamically at the bottom of an asp.net gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on an asp.net webforms C# gridview. It is a nested gridview. Each  child grid will have only two rows. The second row of the each child grid will have an action button at the last column. Up to this point I have completed and  everything is working fine. Depending upon the data type, I have to add four buttons to some of the child rows at the bottom. My entire child grid is created dynamically and added to the parent grid. The child grid has six columns, which I create as a boundfield and either set the text to a value or add a button to the sixth column. If needed I could change them into template fields. I am not sure whether a footer of a template field can be used to add the four buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is little info to go on, but since you state that you create the Nested Grid dynamically i think you are familiar with the RowDataBound event. You can use that to add Buttons as well. In this snippet I add the buttons to the footer row, so you have to enable that row in the nested grid: `ShowFooter="true"`

```
bool primary = false;

protected void NestedGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the current row is a datarow or a footer row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (column == value)
        {
            primary = true;
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer && primary == true)
    {
        //create 4 buttons in a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            //create a new button
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Button " + (i + 1);

            //add a click handler to the button
            button.Click += Button1_Click;

            //add the button to the footer row
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Because you are adding controls dynamically to the GridView, databinding has to occur on every page load, so move the databinding outside the `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }` check.

Comment: Thanks. This is the route I am going. But I don't know how to create and add a footer row dynamically. Simply doing gvChild.ShowFooter = true is not working.

Comment: You don't need to add one, it is already there (not tested with dynamically created grids though). But you don't need to use the footer, if you know the number of rows in the nested grid you could also use `DataControlRowType.DataRow` and add the buttons if it is the last row.

Comment: You are right. Now I see the footer. I have to add the buttons to the footer only if  a field value in the DataRow equals to "Primary". The problem is that by the time I am in if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) I don't have access to the value in the DataRow. Anyway how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer, basically you check the rows for a certain value and set a `bool` accordingly to check in the footer. Don't forget to reset the bool in the parent OnRowDataBound.